# Has it yet been proven that $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{1}{x_{n}}$ with $x_0=2$ is unbounded?

Tags: recurrence-relations, open-problem

> Consider the following recursive formula: $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{1}{x_{n}}$$ with $x_0=2$. Is the sequence produced by this formula unbounded?

Some time ago I came across this problem somewhere on the internet. According to [this paper](http://www.math.grinnell.edu/~chamberl/papers/mario_digits.pdf) on the subject, the question was open at the time it has been published. But I can't seem to find any evidence wether it has been proven already or wether it is still open. Does anybody know?

Of course a proof is more than welcome if you happen to know how to solve it.

*EDIT: I don't understand why my question is being marked as a duplicate. It clearly asks something else than the suggested duplicate, namely wether the problem has yet been solved or not, while the duplicate asks about the problem itself. Also, the redirects on the suggested duplicate, and redirects on the redirects, don't seem to provide an answer to my question either. Am I missing something here?* [No longer relevant, however I'll leave this text for clarity.]

EDIT 2: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226876/is-the-sequence-a-n1-a-n-frac1a-n-a-0-2-bounded) is the page my question was (falsely) marked as a duplicate to and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690150/has-this-chaotic-map-been-studied) is another interesting question about the same problem. I thought I'd add these pages, because they contain some ideas regarding the question and since I get the feeling it is still unanswered, it might be nice to have these accessible from one place.

Comment: @Koro Why do you think the sequence is decreasing? Try evaluating it something like 10 times, and you will see it jumps back and forth in a chaotic fashion.

Comment: Right! My bad! It isn't a decreasing sequence.

Comment: It decreases until $|x|<1$ then blows up and then decreases again gradually until $|x|<1$ again. Since the amount it blows up to depends on a pseudo-random remaining fractional value after a long series of decrements by small amounts, it seems very likely to be unbounded.