# Find $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-\frac{1}{x}) dx$, given$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx=1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Let $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx=1$$
> Then, find
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) dx$$

I subtituted $x=t-\frac{1}{t}$ in the original equation and found $$\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(t-\frac{1}{t}) dt= \frac 12$$

But, I couldn't proceed after this.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more your result ?

Comment: There must be something you're not telling us - knowing the first integral does not determine the second. (Also the you did the substitution wrong...)

Comment: You should graph the change of variables to figure out what the new bounds will look like, and you have to figure out what the relationship between $dx$ and $dt$

Comment: This is a special case of the [Glasser's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem), although it has long been known before Glasser (such as Pólya and Szegö).

Comment: The is question B4 from the 1968 Putnam exam. https://web.archive.org/web/20080330184108/http://www.kalva.demon.co.uk/putnam/putn68.html

Answer (score 5):

Split $( -\infty, \infty)\to ( -\infty, 0) + ( 0, \infty) $
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) \overset{x\to -\frac1x}{ dx}\\
=& \int^{\infty}_{0}f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) \frac {dx}{x^2}+ \int^{0}_{-\infty}f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) \frac {dx}{x^2}\\ =&\ \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{0}f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left( 1+\frac1{x^2}\right) \overset{x\to x-\frac1x}{dx} + \frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left( 1+\frac1{x^2}\right) \overset{x\to x-\frac1x}{dx}\\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1
\end{align}

Comment: See   https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11785-010-0095-0  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690150/has-this-chaotic-map-been-studied/2578363#2578363 ; the correct answer is $1$ not $1/2$.  The map $x\mapsto x-1/x$ is a 2-branched covering.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, $g(x) = x - \frac{1}{x}$. Then

$$\chi_{[a,b]} \circ g = \chi_{\left[\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4}}{2}, \frac{b + \sqrt{b^2 + 4}}{2}\right]}(x) + \chi_{\left[\frac{a - \sqrt{a^2  +4}}{2}, \frac{b - \sqrt{b^2 + 4}}{2}\right]}(x)$$

But $$\mu\left(\left[\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4}}{2}, \frac{b + \sqrt{b^2 + 4}}{2}\right] \cup \left[\frac{a - \sqrt{a^2 + 4}}{2}, \frac{b - \sqrt{b^2 + 4}}{2}\right]\right) = b - a$$ so $g$ is measure preserving and it follows that the result is 1.

Comment: Nice - didn’t expect to see measure theory used in a standard integral problem!