# Evaluate $1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4+\vdots}}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

> Evaluate the infinite continued fraction $$\xi = [1,2,3,4,5\cdots] = 1+\dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{1}{3+\dfrac{1}{4+\vdots}}}$$

There is no periodic behavior of this continued fraction, I am not even sure that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} [1,2,3,\cdots,n]$ exists or not. Any hints on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could a continued fraction with 1 in all numerators and all entries strictly positive ever fail to converge?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681993/why-is-1-frac11-frac11-ldots-not-real

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871733/convergence-of-a-harmonic-continued-fraction.

Comment: @Sabhrant That's not strictly positive entries. The numerators are all $-1$.